# Graph has vertices 8 and without cycles of length 4

Tags: graph-theory

> What is the maximum number of edges can be a simple graph with $8$ vertices, in which there are no cycles of length $4$?

#### My work so far:

Let $t (n) -$ response (number of edges) for a graph with $n$ vertices. I think $t(8)=11$. I can give an example, but can not prove.

[image]

Please help

Comment: Why do you think 11 is the answer? You basically still haven't shown us any own work, you just reworded the original question...

Comment: I can give example for 11

Comment: Apparently 11 is the answer: https://oeis.org/search?q=A006855&language=english&go=Search

Comment: I think the way to show that $11$ is correct would be to demonstrate somehow that the $210$ different 4-cycles in $K_8$ cannot be covered by $16$ edges. (A solution with $12$ edges would be missing $16$ edges in $K_8$, these missing edges need to break each potential cycle).

Comment: @Servaes: Here's how I count: There are $8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot 5=1680$ 4-cycles if we equip each of them with a starting vertex and a direction. Each "naked" cycle is counted $8$ times by this, so the number of cycles must be $1680/8=210$.

Comment: A not too cumbersome way to arrive at the upper bound of $11$ is to first bound the number of vertices of degree greater than $3$. My efforts haven't been very elegant though.